# Entity Framework opening connections to database and not using them

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 DB first for a project. The database is owned by a DBA. He is (and so am I) wondering why EF opens up so many connections the the database that it never uses.

See the below picture, EF has opened up a lot of connections to the database, all from the same host (the hosting IIS server) and for many of them it never even makes a query.

Is this some sort of "there might be a query so I'm gonna make a connection" just in case type of thing?

[image]

Comment: I've never seen EF do this and I can't think of any autonomous process in a context doing this. Are you sure EF is doing this? The application name is just a connection string value. Any process using the connection string will add these logging lines.

Comment: Only one thing connected to that database besides the activity monitor and that is the EF from IIS server code.